# Synonym for "the end of"

Tags: synonyms

Basically, I wanted to paraphrase the following sentence :

*These subjects have been profoundly studied since **the end of** 1950’s.*

What could I use instead of the bold part?  Please make light on me. Thanks!

Comment: The question depends on whether or not you are including *some* of the later years in the 1950s in the phrase. If you only mean from 1960 on, then *end of* is redundant and need not be said. (In fact, it makes the meaning ambiguous.) It's impossible say what you *could* say unless you state what you are *trying* to say.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Thanks for every letter you wrote. I am so sorry for the ones who did -1 for this little question. It's surprisingly interesting that is closed so soon. I am not a native, so my mind makes questions about English. I wonder which rules are monitoring the questions? If someone knows the answer so would he ask some? Is this believable that I who are more than 7 years here, ask a off topic? Who did vote for that moderator who were not used to think deeply before any actions? I am so sorry Jason.  I t's so ridicules if someone think that I want to get +100k for this question. Ha ha.

Comment: Off topic!!! Yes by their measurements it is indeed. I am so sorry for this site, however, it has been very helpful. Messy things circulating around the site making it weak. Thanks for the comment again and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... since the end of *the* 1950s.

... since the late 1950s.

... since late in the 1950s.

... post 1959.

... since 1960.

Suppose the issues began to be studied extensively because of some event, such as the publication of a book about them, cited as J.Smith, 1959.

... post publication of J.Smith, 1959.

... since the publication of J.Smith, 1959.

... since the stir caused by the publication of J.Smith, 1959.

... since fashions changed post publication of J.Smith, 1959.